# NGINX base location sub-paths each with different TLS certificate and key

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

**Problem:** Our NGINX implementation has a base location for several different operation types, e.g. /analytics, /topology, ...; and each has its own *access_by_lua_file* which cracks open a token that is passed in containing several things that must be verified and processed, including a new right-side path, complete with its own cert, key and ca.  The problem we have is there does not seem to be a way to wildcard the *proxy_ssl_certificate*, *proxy_ssl_certificate_key* and *proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate* variables since they require static file paths.

**Question:** Is there any way to configure the cert and key dynamically, even if we take a performance hit?  We are aware of the following restrictions but are frankly surprised no workaround has yet shown up on the internet.

There are 2 reasons for this lack of support:

1. Nginx needs to load the whole SSL server configuration at start
   time, so it throws an error when the certificate or key does not
   exist.
2. The Nginx SSL configuration parser does not expand user defined
   variables so it needs a relative or absolute path.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ssl_certificate_by_lua_block and https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler so I actually found both of those and injected them along with the ssl_clear_certs into the lua code and received this, which I think demonstrates it does not work.

ignoring stale global SSL error (SSL: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:Type=RSA error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib ...

Answer (score 1):

Below is a sequence of SSL API calls I use within one of my OpenResty module.

```
ssl.clear_certs()
ssl.cert_pem_to_der()
ssl.set_der_cert()
ssl.priv_key_pem_to_der()
ssl.set_der_priv_key()
```

Actually it is exactly the same as on https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/ssl.md#synopsis

Comment: Can you tell me if the PEM files have the CRLFs removed, mine still have them but the APIs never throw an error.  After I have done exactly what you show up there in LUA, I return to nginx and the next statement is the proxy_pass call, which throws the 400 in my browser, so perhaps its something on the browser side?

Comment: @ErickGriffin Your code (in your answer) miss set_der_priv_key() call. The sequence from my answer works for me. I used pem files as they generated by openssl utility.

Comment: set_der_priv_key is there.  What I failed to mention is that the variables in each one of these, since the documentation said "no context", actually contain the PEM content as a string, its not a string containing the name of a file but the actual PEM value.  For example, key = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----...", not sure that is OK but no error is thrown there.

Comment: I think I got it to work finally, was missing proxy_ssl_server_name in the conf file, not sure why that would give me that strange error.  Now I am fighting the message, "400 Bad Request - The SSL certificate error"

Answer (score 0):

The proposed answer to this problem does not appear to work.  Here is the code:

```
if cert ~= nil and key ~= nil then

    -- clear the fallback certificates and private keys that are statically
    -- set by the ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key in proxy.conf
    -- directives
    ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, 'Clearing fallback certificates');
    local ok, err = ssl.clear_certs()
    if not ok then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to clear existing (fallback) certificates")
        return ngx.exit(ngx.ERROR)
    end

    ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, 'Convert private key pem to DER format');
    -- key already contains the private key as provided in token
    local client_key, err = ssl.priv_key_pem_to_der(key);
    if not client_key then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to convert PEM priv key to DER: ", err)
        return
    end

    ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, 'Set private key DER');
    ok, err = ssl.set_der_priv_key(client_key)
    if not ok then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to set DER priv key: ", err)
        return
    end

    ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, 'Convert certificate pem to DER format');
    -- cert already contains the private key as provided in token
    local client_cert, err = ssl.cert_pem_to_der(cert);
    if not client_cert then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to convert PEM cert to DER: ", err)
        return
    end

    ngx.log(ngx.DEBUG, 'Set certificate DER');
    ok, err = ssl.set_der_cert(client_cert)
    if not ok then
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to set DER cert: ", err)
        return
    end
end


ngx.log(ngx.INFO, 'Passing request to: ', ngx.var.target)
```

The output:

```
2018/03/06 13:55:31 [debug] 31#0: *12 [lua] analytics_access.lua:270: Clearing fallback certificates
2018/03/06 13:55:31 [debug] 31#0: *12 [lua] analytics_access.lua:277: Convert private key pem to DER format
2018/03/06 13:55:31 [debug] 31#0: *12 [lua] analytics_access.lua:285: Set private key DER
2018/03/06 13:55:31 [debug] 31#0: *12 [lua] analytics_access.lua:292: Convert certificate pem to DER format
2018/03/06 13:55:31 [debug] 31#0: *12 [lua] analytics_access.lua:300: Set certificate DER
2018/03/06 13:55:31 [info] 31#0: *12 [lua] analytics_access.lua:309: Passing request to: https://blah blah...
```

And on the console:
**400 Bad Request
No required SSL certificate was sent**

Comment: Should I use parse_pem_cert, parse_priv_key and the set_cert, set_key for each instead of the above?  Going to try that instead.